# How to deploy an angular 2/4 application on to web hosting?

Tags: angular, deployment, server, hosting

I have created a local copy of angular 4 project and Now everything is working fine in local.
So I just wanted to deploy the angular application to my shared web hosting to access globally, what should I do?

Comment: ehm deploy it^^ I don't really understand the question

Comment: suppose i have created an angular js 4 application on local system, and now i want that application on the live server i can access from anywhere from the internet

Comment: `ng build --prod` will create a `dist` folder with all files you need, which can be copied to your server. Voila, your app is running.

Answer (score 2):

Open command prompt and goto project folder then run

```
ng build
```

To optimize for production use,

```
ng build --prod
```

more command can found here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

This will generate a **dist** folder. Upload the content of **dist** folder to your web server **wwwroot** directory. Now you can access your Angular app.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget to change `base url` in the `index.html` of build(dist) like this

```
<base href="./">
```

or you can simply call flag as well will running build command

```
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
```